# Cannot set Toolbar menu with NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I'm trying to combine NavigationDrawer with a Toolbar that has a refresh Menu option:

[image: screenshot]

The problem I'm encountering is that I cannot make the Toolbar show the menu button.

My `MainActivity` only holds a Fragment. `activity_main.xml`:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_container"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/main" />
```

`MainActivity.kt`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

`nav_main`:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/drawerFragment"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/drawerFragment"
        android:name="com.example.rocketman.drawer.DrawerFragment"
        android:label="DrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_drawer"
        />
</navigation>
```

Basically my MainActivity navigates directly into a DrawerFragment, which is here:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rocketman.drawer.DrawerFragment">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.rocketman.drawer.DrawerFragment">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/midnight_blue"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And finally, my `DrawerFragment`:

```
private const val KEY_SELECTED_DRAWER_ITEM = "DRAWER_SELECTED_ITEM_ID_KEY"

class DrawerFragment: Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentDrawerBinding
    private var drawerSelectedItemId = R.id.nav_home

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentDrawerBinding.inflate(inflater)
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar_home)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        savedInstanceState?.let {
            drawerSelectedItemId = it.getInt(KEY_SELECTED_DRAWER_ITEM, drawerSelectedItemId)
        }

        setupDrawer()
        setBackPressedHandler()
    }

    private fun setBackPressedHandler() {
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            if (binding.drawerLayout.isOpen) {
                binding.drawerLayout.close()
            } else {
                findNavController().popBackStack()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState.putInt(KEY_SELECTED_DRAWER_ITEM, drawerSelectedItemId)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    private fun setupDrawer() {
        val controller = binding.drawerNavView.setupWithNavController(
            childFragmentManager,
            findNavController(),
            listOf(
                //all the items on the Drawer have their own navigation graph
                R.navigation.home,
                R.navigation.rocket,
                R.navigation.company
            ),
            R.id.drawer_container,
            drawerSelectedItemId,
            requireActivity().intent
        )

        controller.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            { navController ->
                NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
                    binding.toolbarHome,
                    navController,
                    binding.drawerLayout
                )

                drawerSelectedItemId = navController.graph.id
            }
        )
    }
}
```

In other words, the Drawer has three items: `home`, `rocket` and `company` as can be seen here, `menu/drawer`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:checked="true"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/nav_menu_home"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_rocket"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_rocket"
        android:title="@string/nav_menu_rocket_list"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_company"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_company"
        android:title="@string/nav_menu_company_data"
        />
</menu>
```

Each of `home`, `rocket` and `company` have their own navigation graph, for example `navigation/company` looks like this:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_company"
    app:startDestination="@id/companyDataFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/companyDataFragment"
        android:name="com.example.rocketman.company.CompanyFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_menu_company_data"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_company_data"
        />
</navigation>
```

And the `CompanyFragment` is straight forward:

```
class CompanyFragment: Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentCompanyDataBinding
    private val vm by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(CompanyVM::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        Repo.init(requireContext())
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentCompanyDataBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.company, menu)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupObservers()
    }

    private fun setupObservers() {
        //observing
    }
}
```

That part works.

However, I want to create a menu action for `Company`. So first I create a menu item `menu/company`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_refresh_24"
        android:title="@string/menu_company_update"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />
</menu>
```

Then in `CompanyFragment` I call `override onCreate() { setHasOptionsMenu(true) }` and `override onCreateOptionsMenu() { inflater.inflate(R.menu.company, menu }`.

This should create the options menu for the Toolbar. However, the Fragment only shows the drawer menu icon but not the options menu icon.

I can add a Toolbar to the content Fragment itself but then the app has two Toolbars, the one with the drawer and the one with option items:
[image: screenshot]

How do I make the Toolbar have both the NavigationDrawer and option items?

Comment: Why do you have a separate `DrawerFragment` at all here? Everything it is doing is typically what your activity should be doing. You don't show where you actually create your `CompanyFragment` and add it to your layout. Where does that happen?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I added a `DrawerFragment` because it made more sense to me as it's an UI element. I also added `Company`'s navigation component and the fragment itself.

Answer (score 1):

Still many people continue to use ActionBar, we don't have to use it any more. And if I were you, I would not use ActionBar and `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` which is related to ActionBar, but just would use a Toolbar.

Just delete `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`, `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` (if you have it).

Instead, use `Toolbar.inflateMenu()` and `Toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener()` directly on your Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you want to display overflow menu along with drawer menu.

The showAsAction option in the menu xml file is what you can use to control how that single menu option will show up in the actionbar.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_refresh_24"
        android:title="@string/menu_company_update"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />
</menu>
```

change this to

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_refresh_24"
        android:title="@string/menu_company_update"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />
</menu>
```

This will show the menu item in the Overflow menu.

Comment: Your solution results in there being an overflow menu instead of the action icon. That's not what I'm asking for. My problem is that the toolbar doesn't show anything but the drawer.

Comment: Have you set setHasOptionsMenu(true) in the fragment? I didn't see that in the above code.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, forgot to paste it into the code. Edited.